# Thread that talk with UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I have this code:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GeneraListaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void GeneraListaCartelle()
{
    try
    {
        ... some operation ....
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message);
    }
}

GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
{
    ... process finished...
}
```

and `txtErrors` is in the "main" thread (the UI). When I catch an error, the asynch thread cannot write to the UI control, and I get an `invalid cross-thread exception`.

Can I dialogate with the UI inside a Thread?

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: What kind of applicaiton, winform or WPF, if WinForm look for [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx), for WPF, look for [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

Comment: I'm using WinForm, sorry ;)

Comment: All answers given below are correct. Additionally, because you may find yourself writing the same code way too often (if you are going to have many cross thread operations), take a look at this as well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37413/A-Generic-Method-for-Cross-thread-Winforms-Access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if You are targetting WinForm Application then:

```
try
    {
        ... some operation ....
    }
catch (Exception err)
    {
       if (txtErrors.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtErrors.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(
                delegate { txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message); })
                );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WinForms, you will need to Invoke your method on the UI-thread like

```
catch (Exception err)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired){
        Action<Exception> act = ((ex) => {
            txtErrors.AppendText(ex.Message);
        }); 
        this.Invoke(act, new object[] { err });
    }
    else{
        txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message);
    }
}
```

If you are using WPF you will need to

```
catch (Exception err)
{
    if(this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()){
       txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message);
    }
    else {
           Action<Exception> act = ((ex) => {
            txtErrors.AppendText(ex.Message);
           }); 
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(act, new object[] { err });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
// This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting
// the text property on a TextBox control.
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

// This method demonstrates a pattern for making thread-safe
// calls on a Windows Forms control. 
//
// If the calling thread is different from the thread that
// created the TextBox control, this method creates a
// SetTextCallback and calls itself asynchronously using the
// Invoke method.
//
// If the calling thread is the same as the thread that created
// the TextBox control, the Text property is set directly.
private void SetText(string text)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false in the called form_load event handler

Answer (score 1):

Pulled this out of an old project where I had to deal with updating the UI from another thread. Should work for you as well.

```
delegate void addtoValProg();
addtoValProg myDelegate;

myDelegate = new addtoValProg(invokeControl);

private void GeneraListaCartelle()
{
    try
    {
        //... some operation ....
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        invokeControl();
    }
}

private void invokeControl()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(this.myDelegate);
    }
    else
    {
        txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message);
        txtErrors.Update();
    }
}
```